# How i can make an message "seen" indicator responsive?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making a chat application in android studio and i am trying to make a "seen" indicator below the message, but when the message is short (example: "Hello, what's up") the seen indicator stays below message box. When the message is longer, the message box gets bigger and "seen" indicator goes into the message box. How i can make it responsible? Here is the code for the sent_message.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="@dimen/_4sdp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_sent_message"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_4sdp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_13ssp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDateTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
        android:text="17:32 PM"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textMessage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seenIndicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
        android:text="Seen"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_35sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textMessage"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this inside the `textMessage` text-view:

```xml
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopof="@id/seenIndicator"
```

Comment: It doesn't work..

Comment: I have edited, please check.

Comment: It gives me an error: "AAPT: error: attribute layout_constraintBottom_toTopof (aka com.primo.chatapp:layout_constraintBottom_toTopof) not found."